# How to test child component based on property that is sent to it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, chai, enzyme

I am having a component where I have a child component that I am sending a property from the local state:

```
   <PeriodModal
      showModal={this.state.showModalPeriod}
      periode={periodeSlett}
      cancelEvent={this.hideModal}
      closeEvent={this.removePeriode}
    />
```

Now, when I am trying to unit test the component, and set the local state of `showModalPeriod` to `true` to see if the `PeriodModal` component is visible, I get an error:

> AssertionError: expected { length: 0 } to have a length of 1 but got 0
>         + expected - actual

This is how I am doing this test:

```
it('will show the PeriodModal when showModalPeriod is true', () => {
    const reduxFormChange = sinon.spy();
    const reduxClearFields = sinon.spy();

    const wrapper = shallowWithIntl(<FaktaForm
      readOnly
      disableButtons
      reduxFormChange={reduxFormChange}
      reduxClearFields={reduxClearFields}
    />);

    wrapper.setState({ showModalPeriod: true });
    const periodModal  = wrapper.find('PeriodModal ');
    expect(periodModal).to.have.length(1);
  });
```

I have also tried with importing the component first and using the component in find function:

```
const periodModal = wrapper.find(PeriodModal );
```

This is how to component PeriodModal looks like(I am only showing the relevant stuff):

```
const PeriodModal = ({
  showModal,
  closeEvent,
  cancelEvent,
  periode,
}) => {
  return (
    <Modal
      className={styles.modal}
      isOpen={showModal}
      contentLabel="Perioden slettes"
      onRequestClose={closeEvent}
      closeButton={false}
    >

    </Modal>
  );
};

PeriodModal.propTypes = {
  showModal: PropTypes.bool,
  closeEvent: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  cancelEvent: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  periode: PropTypes.shape().isRequired,
};
```

How can I test my case?

Comment: Might just be a typo, `wrapper.find('PeriodModal ');` change it to `wrapper.find('PeriodModal');` or try `wrapper.find(PeriodModal);` after importing it in the test

Comment: sorry, that was a typo here, it is correct in the actual code

Comment: is there any conditional rendering in your FaktaForm component?

Comment: @eramit2010 yes, that was it, I forget to change the lenght of the other component, thanks for reminding me about that!